# ReduceByKey function on JavaPairRDD giving value length one

Tags: mapreduce, apache-spark

I have a JavaPairRDD named "trimMap" each line of which is as follows

```
key,lat1,lon1,val1,lat2,lon2,val2,dist,variogram,1
------------------------------------------------------------    
4,213,218,482.6,226,221,800.1,18.384776310850235,100806.25,1
```

The last one is for counting the number of entries for a specific key. The code I have written is as follows

```
JavaPairRDD<String, String> counts = trimMap.reduceByKey(new  Function2<String, String, String>(){

        @Override
        public String call(String a, String b) throws Exception {


            String[] firstSplit = a.split(",");
            //String[] secondSplit = b.split(",");

            //String first = firstSplit[8];
            //String second = secondSplit[8];

            return Integer.toString(firstSplit.length);//Integer.toString((Integer.parseInt(first)+Integer.parseInt(second)));
        }

});
```

I want to add the ones. But when I print the length of firstSplit or secondSplit it gives 1, whereas the length I expected is 8.

~Regards,
Chandan

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully Spark has a built in function to count the number of times each key appears which we can use instead `countByKey()` http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html#countByKey() (which returns a map of key to count). That being said if you want to do this the way you are doing it (e.g. if it can have values other than 1) you might want to look into `aggregateByKey` http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html#aggregateByKey(U, org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2, org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2) (that way you don't have to do funky things with everything being a string).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please tell me why the string arrays  are length 1?

Comment: Because I have to do calculations on other fields as well.

Comment: So reduceByKey uses the same combiner function when its combining between values in a partition or combining already combined values from different partitions. You really probably want `aggregateByKey`

Comment: I want to split the string value with "," separator. Is that possible with aggregateByKey? reduceByKey and aggregateByKey both seem to be almost same.

Comment: You can think of aggregateByKey as a superset of reduceByKey, if you can do it with reduceByKey you can do it with aggregateByKey (although reduceByKey is great for when it fits since it's much simpler, but it isn't a great fit here). If you are set on using reduceByKey I would first do a map to split it into key / value you care about and then do the reduction. Does that make sense?

Comment: I want the "value" part of "trimMap" JavaPairRDD to be split with "," separator. I could not do that.

Comment: I take it then that you are trying to operate on multiple values within each key, and you should really consider using aggregateByKey then instead.

Comment: Okay. I am giving it a try.